# chef logging of wget

Tags: bash, logging, chef-infra, recipe

I have a chef recipe that looks something like:

```
Chef::Log.info('step1')
# do stuff

Chef::Log.info('step2')
bash "do_wget" do
  code <<-EOF
  wget somefile
  EOF
end

Chef::Log.info('step3')
# do stuff
```

The wget takes a while but the logging ends up looking like

```
step1    
step2    
step3
bash script runs #indicates that the bash script from step 2 is running
```

Is there a way to prevent the logging from step3 until the bash script is done executing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should get acquainted with [Anatomy of Chef Run](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run). It has 2 stages: compiling and executing.

No action is taken on the resources in the recipes at compiling stage - each evaluated resource is just taken and put into the **Resource Collection**. Plain Ruby code outside of resources is evaluated, however.

In execution stage it actually evaluates **Resource Collection**. But by this moment all your logging messages are already printed out.

If you need to run ruby code (including Chef logging) on execution stage, there is a special resource for that [Ruby Block](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-RubyBlock)

```
ruby_block "Add logging step3" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info('step3')
  end
  action :create
end
```

Another way may be, is to actually execute resource in compiling stage:

```
bash "do_wget" do
  code "wget somefile"
  action :nothing
end.run_action :run
```

Action :nothing is set to avoid running this resource twice (once in every stage).

Comment: It depends on, when you need your log to appear. I actually don't see any benefit in logging during execution phase like that. But, yes, you can skip the `action :create` line. then it will be 5 lines.

Comment: Well during development with vagrant it could be useful. Thanks for the answer, upvoted ;)

Comment: You can set `chef.log_level = :debug` for your chef provisioner in Vagrantfile, then the resource itself will write down much more info. Though it's not mentioned in documentation http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html, the property actually exists if you check the source code https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/provisioners/chef/config/base.rb

Comment: Great job explaining the reason with the anatomy link. It should be mentioned that you could use a log resource, which will log the statement in the execution phase: http://docs.getchef.com/resource_log.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the log resource instead, which I understand runs at the execution stage as you require

```
log "step2" do
    :info
end
```

or simply

```
log "step 3"
```

http://docs.opscode.com/resource_log.html

Comment: I find that the log resource can't be notified (atleast in chef 12)

Comment: Set `action :nothing` then notify like this `notifies :write, 'log[step2]', :delayed`?